# Java Card have a weird response to APDU with INS = 0x70

Tags: javacard, smartcard-reader, pcsc, globalplatform

Below, you see a simple applet that returns `0x6781` to incoming APDU commands with INS=`0x70` or INS=`0x71`:

```
package testPack;
import javacard.framework.*;

public class TestApp extends Applet
{

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) 
    {
        new TestApp().register(bArray, (short) (bOffset + 1), bArray[bOffset]);
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu)
    {
        if (selectingApplet())
        {
            return;
        }

        byte[] buf = apdu.getBuffer();
        switch (buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS])
        {
        case (byte)0x70:
            ISOException.throwIt((short)0x6781);
            break;
        case (byte)0x71:
            ISOException.throwIt((short)0x6781);
            break;
        default:
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that, I receive `0x6C01` to the APDU command with INS=`0x70`:

```
Send: 00 A4 04 00 07 01 02 03 04 05 00 00 00
Recv: 90 00

Send: 00 70 00 00 00
Recv: 6C 01
Send: 00 70 00 00 01
Recv: 01 90 00

Send: 00 71 00 00 00
Recv: 67 81
```

I tried two different Java Cards (One is NXP JCOP v2.4.2 r3 and another is a KONA java card) through both contact and contactless interfaces and using two different cap file generated inside two different laptops via two different IDE!!!( How Suspicious am I? :D ) But the response is equal.

I suspect to the PCSC or Card Manager for this weird response. Because in the simulator, even the `process` method doesn't called for this special INS value.

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INS = 70`with `CLA = 00` is the MANAGE CHANNEL command according to the ISO-7816 specification, as well as `INS = A4` means SELECT.

If you want to use these INS codes, you must use `CLA >= 0x80` in order to specify that it is your proprietary command.

Comment: Thank you dear Vojta. Does these special values are limited to SELECT APDU command and MANAGE CHANNEL APDU command only? Or I must use another CLA other than 0x00 for all the other ISO7816 commands as well? I mean, for example, can I use `A2` as INS with CLA=00 in my applet or because it is defined for SEARCH RECORD, I must avoid using it with CLA=0x00 too? (May you please check your gmail for that SIM Card applet development related question too?)

Answer (score 1):

I think if class represent interindustry class then only INS will work as defined in standard,Here CLA - 00 represent interindusty command therefore, card response behvaiour was like same behaviour as Manage channel command because you used INS = 70.

```
 6.16.4 Response message (nominal case)

Table 73 - MANAGE CHANNEL response APDU
Data field  Logical channel number if P1-P2='0000'
Empty if P1-P2!='0000'
SW1-SW2     Status bytes
```

actually your card was returning logical channel no -01 to you. [ManageChannel](http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_6_basic_interindustry_commands.aspx#chap6_16)

it seems to me that if class is propriatry. here INS will not treated as defined INS in standard. Hope CLA 80 with same INS 0x70 will give you require result.

hope it helps.

```
[Bit 8 set to 1 indicates the proprietary class]
```